# Generalised principle of counting why do we multiply when there is no order?

Tags: self-study

The following is from Ross "Introduction to probability and statistics for engineers and scientists" Example 3.5.4

We choose 6 pairs of room mates from a team of 12 basketball players.
It follows from the generalized basic principle of counting that there are

$$\left(\begin{array}{c}12 \\ 2\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{c}10 \\ 2\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{l}8 \\ 2\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{l}6 \\ 2\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{l}4 \\ 2\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{l}2 \\ 2\end{array}\right)=\frac{12 !}{(2 !)^{6}}$$

ways of dividing the players into a first pair, a second pair and so on.

> Hence there are $$(12) ! / 2^{6} 6 !$$ ways of dividing the players
> into 6 (unordered) pairs of 2 each.

My question is: Why do we multiply by $6!$ given we are told that the pairs are unordered?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's dividing by $6!$, not multiplying: $12!/(2^66!)$.

There are $12!$ ordered ways to pair up, divided by $2^6$ because within-pair ordering doesn't matter, then divided by $6!$ because across-pair ordering doesn't matter.

Comment: So bracket in the wrong spot really

Answer (score 2):

The only thing I'd add to Thomas Lumley's answer is these quotes from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations#Mixed_division_and_multiplication):

> ... there can be ambiguity in the use of the slash symbol / in expressions such as 1/2n...

> ... the manuscript submission instructions for the Physical Review Review journals state that multiplication is of higher precedence than division with a slash...